# condition_variable::wait_for always waits?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some code in a unit test that waits until my vector is sufficiently big:

```
bool waitForOutwardMessages(size_t size, int millis) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    return ready.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(millis), [=]{
        return this->messages.size() >= size;
    });
}

std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable ready;
```

Easy enough. Except when I run this test, I'm expecting that the the vector in question should fill up on the order of milliseconds after I make this call on the other thread. Maybe 10ms, maybe 100ms, certainly within 1s. But when I pass in 5000 as the `millis` argument, this function *always* waits 5 seconds.

On the one hand, this is fine, because I don't care how long this test takes anyway. On the other hand, I thought it was supposed to wait up to the duration only if the condition variable wasn't notified... not always?

Is there a way to get this to return earlier?

Comment: Are you doing a signal or broadcast on ready correctly? It's entirely possible that you send the signal because the wait_for call gets executed.

Comment: @JesusRamos Yes, that was actually it :( The one case I didn't notify() was the one case that I was actually testing here. Thanks!! Should I just delete the question?

Comment: Question is still valid, I can switch my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are actually calling signal or broadcast on `ready`. There's a possible race if you're not careful where you can signal the condition before you actually wait on it (which will cause a wait until timeout).

Comment: This actually happens? The new C++ library code doesn't check the predicate *before* beginning the wait? That's kind of ... dumb.

Comment: I just checked and the condition wait IS supposed to be checking the Predicate before releasing the lock and beginning the wait. So there is no possible race condition, IF the code is properly locking every access that changes the predicate.

Comment: @ZanLynx The key is in the if, sometimes people forget about the lock on the signal/broadcast.

Comment: You don't want to be holding the lock when you send the broadcast. That is another mistake. Depending on the implementation/OS, the listeners might wake up, then immediately hit the lock and go back to sleep. Lock, change the predicate, unlock, signal.

Comment: OK, perhaps sending the signal inside the lock isn't a mistake really. It just is not the way I would do it because of the performance implications.

Comment: Consider the fact that you check the variable with the lock. It's not satisfied. Then the condition_variable unlocks. Before this thread actually registers itself to be notified and goes to sleep, a context switch occurs to another thread which then satisfies the condition and notifies the `ready` variable. A context switch occurs back to this thread which then finishes `ready.wait_for()`, registering `this_thread` for notification and going to sleep thinking that the condition is not satisfied. Thus, the solution is to maintain the lock for the duration of the call to `ready.notify_*()`.